OpenCV(4.10.0) не может найти файл arm64-v8a в проекте Android Studio
Я импортировала OpenCV в проект отдельным модулем, сделала его module dependency для модуля app, но при команде:
videoCapture.open(File(uri).absolutePath, CAP_GSTREAMER)
Он выдаёт:

2024-10-09 15:49:31.964 18486-18486 cv::error()ru.ccf  OpenCV(4.10.0) Error: Requested object was not found (could not open directory: /data/app/ru.ccf-LljE92Hajg5Kb8UEFYPUXg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a) in glob_rec, file /home/ci/opencv/modules/core/src/glob.cpp, line 279
ERROR: findInfo

Это может быть из-за того, что у меня org.jetbrains.kotlin.android версии 1.9.22, а не 1.9.25?
Сначала была ошибка в пути файла, и он просто не мог его найти, но теперь у меня путь файла выглядит как file://external/file/5929 и вроде заработало, но появилась эта ошибка.
Если проблема в org.jetbrains.kotlin.android, то я пыталась ставить версию 1.9.25, но тогда возникает проблема с совместимостью модулей...

Вы все по этому списку сделали? https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/df8/tutorial_dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html

Покажите ваш build.gradle
